# Angular reactive form validate nested fields

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using **Angular 7**

I have a nested reactive form

```
this.salonProfileForm = this.fb.group({
  salonName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  address: this.fb.group({
    city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  })
});

get f() {
    return this.salonProfileForm.controls;
}
```

And I have the HTML form like

```
<input type="text" formControlName="salonName" required />
<ng-container *ngIf="submitted && f.salonName.invalid && (f.salonName.dirty || f.salonName.touched)">
   <small *ngIf="f.salonName.errors.required">
      Salon name is required
   </small>
</ng-container>

<div formGroupName="address">
  <input type="text" formControlName="city" />
  <ng-container *ngIf="submitted && f.city.invalid && (f.city.dirty || f.city.touched)">
    <small *ngIf="f.city.errors.required">
        city is required
    </small>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

But this gives error on city input **ng-container** field as

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
```

**How can I validate the nested input fields?**

> console.log(this.f.address)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to access like following:

```
f.address.controls.city.invalid
```

**Edit**

```
export class Home implements OnInit {
  salonProfileForm : FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.salonProfileForm = new FormGroup({
      'salonName': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      'address': new FormGroup({
        'city': new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })
  });
 }

}
```

Moving to `.html` template

```
<form [formGroup]="salonProfileForm " (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<div formGroupName="address">
  <input type="text" formControlName="city" />
  <ng-container *ngIf="!salonProfileForm.get('address.city').valid && salonProfileForm.get('address.city').touched">
    <span>This is required</span>
  </ng-container>
</div>

</form>
```

I have pasted in shape it works , So feel free to update your code to fit the above.

Comment: Still gives the same error. Also the webstorm editor gives `unresolved variable city` error.

Comment: Kindly ``console.log(f.address)`` and show me the output

Comment: Hey, While running the command `ng build --prod`, it gives error ` Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.` on the line where I have the above error check.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq8z9j Check this for the html and ts content

Comment: @AnujTBE Try to add a different question for the last error you get maybe it's not related to this answer

Comment: I was using `FormBuilder`. I changed to `FormGroup` but again the same error while running `ng build --prod --aot`